# Android MVP Architecture - SharedPreference is consider as Model?

Tags: android, architecture, mvp, android-mvp

I been look into a lot of resource about Android MVP. From what I understand Model is the data access layer that solely deal with any work that relate to access data from the storage (database) of the system internally or externally. For example, external database like Firebase, internal database like Realm, etc.

**My uncertainty**

I am unsure about the '**SharedPreference**' in Android, as it acts like a 'Permanent Session' which store the data within the application,

Does it mean that any data retrieval of **SharedPreference** Should be done in the **Model Layer**? or it is okay for me to simply retrieve **SharedPreference** data in View Layer to being displayed on screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that any data retrieval of SharedPreference Should be
>   done in the Model Layer?

Yes

I am working with MVP for about 2 years and here is our team approach: Create a SharedPreferencesManager (Model) class to manage everything that belongs to SharedPreferences because SharedPreferences is a "lite" database (key-value)

It is just an opinion. Hope this help!

Comment: Does it mean that you have to pass the Context Data from View Layer to the Model Layer as well to get the SharedPreference Data?

Comment: Yes, we have to pass context to model layer.

Comment: Is this a good approach? as passing Context (android specific code) which actually would decrease the testability of the Application

Comment: In SQLite or Realm, you have to pass context, too. So I think the trade-off here is acceptable